# How to change the return type depending on the input C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

How would I go about writing a function to return a different type depending on the input. I've tried using a template but I'm not sure I understand what I am doing. If the input is a int I want the output to  be a string and vice versa.

So I tried something like this:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T functionName(T s){

    if(typeid(s).name() == 'i'){
        return "int";
    }
    if(typeid(s).name() == 's'){
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Not sure how to achieve what I'm looking for here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend to use that function afterwards? 
Mean even if C++ syntax would allow defining such a function, what should happen if you have int a = functionName(s) and the function returns a string? C++ is a strong typed language and thus such constructs are not really possible. You have to explicitly avoid it by writing the function multiple times with different return types and handle an error case if the input were to imply returning the wrong type. Another thing you could do is to return a struct or just std::pair<int, string> and only fill one of the two.

Comment: Couldn't you just use auto a = functionName(s) in that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the unique return type must be determined at compile-time; you can't have multiple return statements returning unrelated types.

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.
>
> The return statements in a discarded statement do not participate in function return type deduction

e.g.

```
template <class T>
auto functionName(T s){

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return std::string("int");
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: OP asked opposite, int -> string, string -> int.

Comment: I'll have to look into the documentation of constexpr but it seems to function in the way I was hoping. Is there benefit to this other than brevity in code to function overloading?

Answer (score 5):

Use overloading:

```
const char* foo(int) {
    return "int";
}

int foo(const char*) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: once you wrote the overloads you dont need the template anymore

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, sure. I just wanted to be consistent with OP's function declaration and other answers.

Comment: but using a template was just OPs attempt of solving the problem, it is not a requirement. Reading your answer they might get the impression the template would serve a purpose here, just saying

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, removed template.

Answer (score 4):

You can use template specializations prior C++17 or `if constexpr` in C++17 and newer.

```
template <class U, class T>
U functionName(T s);
template <>
std::string functionName(int s){
    return "int";
}
template <>
int functionName(std::string s){
    return 0;
}
// Or
template <class T>
auto functionName(T s){
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        return 0;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return "int";
    }
    ....
}
```