# How to get a variable and return multiple different datatype variable using auto in c++

Tags: c++, std, auto, crow

I have to convert a rvalue to integer, boolean or string i am unable to convert it is giving the error

error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: ‘int’ and then ‘bool’

```cpp
auto convertData(const crow::json::rvalue &data) {
    std::string type = get_type_str(data.t());
    
    if(type == "Number"){
        return int(data.i());
    } else if(type == "True" || type == "False") {
        return bool(data.b());
    } 

    std::string val = data.s();
    return std::string(val);
}
```

Can someone please help

Edit: -

// See i am currently doing this

```cpp
bsoncxx::document::value doc_value = builder
                                << "id"
                                << count
                                << "name"
                                << reqj["name"].s()
                                << "type"
                                << reqj["type"].s()
                                << "priority"
                                << priority
                                << "expense_type"
                                << reqj["expense_type"].s()
                                << "available"
                                << bool(reqj["available"].b())
                                << "life"
                                << int(reqj["life"].i())
                                << "quantity"
                                << int(reqj["quantity"].i())
                                << finalizer;
bsoncxx::document::view docview = doc_value.view();

bsoncxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::insert_one> result = collection.insert_one(docview);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Now i want to do like this

```cpp
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document update_builder;
            
for (auto it = reqj.begin(); it != reqj.end(); ++it) {
    if(it->key()=="id") continue;
    update_builder << "$set" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
    update_builder << it->key() << convertData(it->value());
    update_builder << bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
}

bsoncxx::document::value update = update_builder << finalizer;

bsoncxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::insert_one> result = collection.insert_one(update_builder());

// The collection.insert_one updates the data in database
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That should really be an answer...

Comment: With `auto` all return statement must use exactly same type. Compiler will deduce what is return type, so you do not have to type it in function declaration. If there is inconsistency in return statements then you will have this error.

Comment: Related: [std::variant vs. std::any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303939/)

Comment: Hi, @463035818_is_not_an_ai even if i use std::variant i have to use std::get<datatype> but the main problem is i dont to use datatype let the convertData handle all and return it

Comment: [How to change the return type depending on the input C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046161/how-to-change-the-return-type-depending-on-the-input-c) and [Returning a type based on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088983/returning-a-type-depending-on-the-parameter)

Comment: " i have to use std::get<datatype>" yes tahts what you will have to do. Why is that a problem? The second part of the comment I do not understad. Perhaps an example of how you plan to use the function would help to clarify. I mean you write either `int x = convertData(x);` or you write `std::string y = convertData(x);`, ie the return type is either `int` or `string`, it cannot be both

Comment: Hi @MarekR is it possible to know the data of variable at runtime ?

Comment: concerning your update: You should read about `std::variant` and `std::visit`. And I expect that the types provided by bisoncxx have mechanisms similar to that

Comment: C++ is statically typed language. So you expect something outside of language design. As point out there are types which can handle multiple types, like `std::variant`

Comment: Hi @user12002570 thanks for the two given link, but they does not work in my case, kindly read the updated problem.

Comment: it does not work in your case because what you ask for it not possible. You cannot make a function return a different type based on a runtime condition.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` return type cannot do that. The type of the returned value must be known statically. You could consider to return a `std::variant<std::string,int>`. However, I suspect that `crow::json::rvalue` is already some kind of variant.

You could make the function a template:

```
template <typename T>
T getAs(const crow::json::rvalue &data);
```

Such that the caller specifies the type:

```
std::string s = getAs<std::string>(x);
```

If it is only 2 types, I would rather recommend to write two overloads: `getAsString` and `getAsInt` though.

Comment: Hi @463035818_is_not_an_ai i appreciate the solution but the main problem is that i dont know if the data is string or int or double also const crow::json::rvalue store data inside as string

Comment: you do know the type `if(type == "Number"){` but only at runtime. Thats what `std::variant` is for. You can let the caller choose what they expect and throw an execption if its the wrong type. But you cannot magically know at compile time already what the type will be

Comment: Hi @463035818_is_not_an_ai i have added more detail to the question